# To show the post in a page of my theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have to show all the posts from custom type post on my product page. So I am using the Custom Post Type plugin. Now I want to display all the posts in the product page like it was a blog page of WordPress. I am using the code below to display the posts in the product page..

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( is_page('product') && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('products' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

But I can't get the page. If there is some other way to display all the posts in the page, then please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be easier to make a specific template for your page, and use `get_posts` function.

To create a specific template for a page :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#What_Template_is_Used_to_Display_a_Particular_Page.3F

How to use get_posts :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Add this code where you want all post's change the ID of category and number of post's...

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'category' => 3 );


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```